# How to wrap ConcurrentSkipListSet to keep a fixed capacity of the latest values in a thread-safe way?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent

I want to wrap [ConcurrentSkipListSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) to keep a fixed capacity of the *latest* (according to [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)) values:

```
private int capacity = 100;
// using Integer just for an illustration
private ConcurrentSkipListSet<Integer> intSet = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>();
```

Therefore, I implemented `put()` like this:

```
// This method should be atomic.
public void put(int value) {
    intSet.add(value);
    if (intSet.size() > capacity)
        intSet.pollFirst();
}
```

However, this `put()` is not thread-safe.

***Note:*** No other mutation methods. Of course, I need "read-only" methods like `getLast()` or `getBefore(Integer value)`.

> How to wrap ConcurrentSkipListSet to keep a fixed capacity of the latest values in a thread-safe way?

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be any way to do this without wrapping the whole thing in a synchronized lock.

Comment: what other mutation methods do you need to execute on the set?

Comment: @jtahlborn No other mutation methods. Of course, I need access methods like `getLast()` or `getBefore(Integer value)`. Thanks for pointing this issue out.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Does this mean that I have also to wrap access methods like `getLast()` or `getBefore(Integer value)` in the same synchronized lock as that used by `put(Integer value)` and I will lose all the concurrency benefits of ConcurrentSkiplistSet?

Comment: Yes, that would follow.  At that point, you might as well use `Collections.synchronizedNavigableSet(TreeSet)`.  I confess I'd be highly surprised if there were a good way to do this and still get the nice concurrency effects.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks for the suggestion. Making it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not likely to be able to do this and get the concurrency benefits of `ConcurrentSkipListSet`.  At that point, you might as well just use `Collections.synchronizedNavigableSet(TreeSet)`, at which point you can just write

```
synchronized (set) {
  set.add(value);
  if (set.size() > cap) {
    set.pollFirst();
  }
}
```